# Word for a particular "weird-looking" pose in a photograph?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, slang

By *weird-looking* I mean something like this, a facial expression that people often use when being photographed.

[image: Man with head thrust forward from shoulders, wide eyes, slightly furrowed eyebrows, and slightly pursed lips.]

I checked [Thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/weird?s=t), but the words--freaky, funky, kooky--don't seem to have the "looking" part. (I'm purely referring to the physical appearance, not the behavior.)

Is there a word/phrase that is close to that meaning?

Comment: Is there a word in your language for this?

Comment: Pretty sure the word for weird-looking is *weird-looking*. :)

Comment: It's a specific pose associated with photography, especially selfies,  so this question is actually asking about specifically relevant slang terms. I have edited the question to point in that direction, so please roll back if that isn't what you're interested in, janoChen.

Comment: I might cause that pose "bug eyed".  (Although there's something a bit fishy about it too.)

Comment: *He stared wide-eyed into the lens*

Comment: This question loses much of its value without the photograph of the person making the funny face, which has disappeared since I posted my answer several months ago. Can you either restore it the original image or replace it with a similar photo?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the particular photo you offer as an example, the person is doing two things: bugging his eyes and doing some version of duck lips or a duck face. Here is the entry for *bug-eyed* in *The Random House Historical Dictionary of American Slang* (1994):

> **bug-eyed** *adj.* having staring eyes, as from fear or astonishment
>
> [First citation:] **1922** in OED2.

*Duck face* is a much more recent slang term, dating to 2006, according to the extensive history of the term at [Know Your Meme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/duck-face). That site defines *duck face* as

> a pejorative term for a facial expression made by pressing one's lips together into the shape of a duck's bill.

There are, of course, more and less exaggerated forms of this expression, and some variations have their own slang names. For example, Know Your Meme also has an entry for [sparrow face](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/sparrow-face) (evidently a translation of the original Japanese チュン顔 or ちゅん顔, which the site says would more literally be rendered as "chirp face"), which it dates to February 2013 and defines as

> a facial expression made by slightly parting one’s lips with eyes wide open.

Technically, I would say that the guy in the OP's photo is doing a manic sparrow face, rather than a duck face. The effect of the combined positioning of eyes and lips is to produce a look that is only slightly more exaggerated than the one that male model Derek Zoolander calls ["Blue Steel"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D519hT7-ytY) (or "Ferrari" or "The Tigre") in the movie [*Zoolander*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoolander).

Comment: The original question was edited earlier today, and I see that the photograph has disappeared—a hazard of image-based language questions, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

grotesque is a possibility although it is perhaps too extreme in this case. It  refers to appearance.

> [grotesque](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=grotesque)
>
> /ɡrə(ʊ)ˈtɛsk/
>
> adjective: grotesque
>
> 1. comically or repulsively ugly or distorted. "a figure wearing a
>      grotesque mask"

Answer (score 1):

You could say that he is an ***[oddball](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/oddball)*** or has an ***[oddball](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/oddball)*** appearance.

> *noun*: a strange or eccentric person.
>
> *adjective*: strange; bizarre.

(OED)

---

**EDIT:** Thinking about it, the exmaple you have provided is of a ***[goggle-eyed](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/goggle-eyed)*** person.

> Having staring or protuberant eyes

(OED)

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess the best approach would be the simplest, and tchrist's comment is appropriate. **He's weird-looking** or **He looks weird**.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the context you might not be looking for synonyms of weird but different ways to describe how they are weird, maybe they appear; 
 **- stiff
 - uneasy
 - unnatural
 - awkward
 - self-conscious
 - artificial**,
is that the kind of thing you're looking for?